# Set method on a map in typescript not working as expected

Tags: javascript, typescript

I've a map describes as

```js
new Map<string, RetrievedMessageBody>
```

where `RetrievedMessageBody` is an interface and have schema like

```js
export interface RetrievedMessageBody{
    hi : string
    bye : string
    goodmorning : string
    goodnight : string[]
}
```

I'm trying to make a config file to set the value of the `map`, the config file look like this

```js
export let body: RetrievedMessageBody = {
    hi: "Not Available",
    bye: "Not Available",
    goodmorning: "Not Available",
    goodnight: [],
};

export let schemasConfig = new Map<string, RetrievedMessageBody>([
    ["A", body],
    ["B", body]
])
```

But when I trying to set the values of body(i.e., "hi" or "bye"), it is not assigning the values. The file from which I'm setting the values looks like this

```js
import {schemasConfig, body} from "../setter/schemas";

schemasConfig.set("A", {...body, 
  "hi" : "sorry",
  "goodnight" : ["goodevening"]
});
```

When I'm logging the value of schemaConfig like this

```
console.log(schemasConfig.get("A"))
```

The output is

```
{
    hi: "Not Available",
    bye: "Not Available",
    goodmorning: "Not Available",
    goodnight: ["goodevening"]
}
```

Expected output

```
{
    hi: "sorry",
    bye: "Not Available",
    goodmorning: "Not Available",
    goodnight: ["goodevening"],
}
```

I'm not sure of what wrong I'm doing here, can someone please point it out.

Comment: How do you know that the saved objects are not being updated?

Comment: Are you trying to assign to existing object `schemasConfig[[A]].foo = bar` or create a new oject `schemasConfig[[A]] == {foo: bar}` ?

Comment: @Pointy I'm trying to log it in the console. I'm having a large number of attributes, I've posted less number of attributes to keep the question simple.

Comment: @Dimava No, I'm just trying to assign different body with the set method

Comment: I see no reason why it would not assign values. Add example `console.log`s into the question (with output / expected comment) maybe

Comment: @Dimava when I'm logging the value in console then the output is like {
    hi: "Not Available",
    bye: "Not Available",
    goodmorning: "Not Available",
    goodnight: ["goodevening"],
};
it should assign the value of "hi" as well acc to the code I've written above

Comment: "*The file from which I'm setting the values*" - are you sure this module is getting loaded  and executed before you do `console.log(schemasConfig.get("A"))`?

Comment: Hi @Bergi, I'm sure it's being loaded because if it hasn't then one of the values won't be updated (goodnight: ["goodevening]")

Comment: @Uttam yeah, but `hi: "sorry",` is not, so there's something else going on that you haven't shown us

Comment: @Bergi hey I'm having a large codebase, I tried my best to simplify things
So before setting the value ho `hi` I logged the value and it is occurring in the console. But I don't know why it's not setting the value. Even there I've used the spread operator and did the same way :(

Comment: Try to put the everything into a single file so that you know the logic is sound. If that doesn't work, please put it in the question as a [mcve]; if it works, you know it's a problem with the imports. Put logs in every involved module so that you can see in which order they load/evaluate and which values the variables hold respectively.

Answer (score 2):

Your `goodnight` property in your `RetrievedMessageBody` is defined as an array of strings. So you also need to assign an array of your `goodnight` property in your `schemasConfig`:

```
import { schemasConfig, body } from "../setter/schemas";

schemasConfig.set("A", {
  ...body,
  hi: "sorry",
  goodnight: ["goodevening"] 
});
```

Comment: Hey @julia, thanks for your solution. Adding [] works for the key `goodnight`. But it is still not working for other attributes that isn't an array :(

Comment: Hey @Uttam, if you want to set values on your strings you can directly assign your new values without your object `..body`.

Comment: When I tried assigning without `...body` like this schemaConfig.set("A",{hi:"thanks"}) then the error occurred saying
Argument of type '{ hi: any; }' is not assignable to parameter of type 'RetrievedMessageBody'.   Type '{ hi: any; }' is missing the following properties from type 'RetrievedMessageBody': bye, goodmorning, goodnight

Answer (score -2):

The problem lies with this part -

```
"goodnight" : "goodevening"
```

"goodnight" accepts an array of strings, not just a string.